# Docusign API Fails using production account

Tags: docusignapi

We are facing a problem while implementing Docusign on  Production Environment.

We have created Integrator Key using demo account xyz@abc.com and moved it to Production account pqr@abc.com.

API works fine for xyz@abc.com but it fails when we use pqr@abc.com saying authentication failed.

URL we are using for Credential API is  https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx.
We tried using Credential API https://docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx but it says “Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'docusign.net'. We are using Tls12 security protocol for communication.

Please suggest how to move forward with this.

Comment: Most likely you need to create a new key with the email id pqr@abc.com for your production account.

Comment: Hello Soumen , Docusign doesnt allow to add new key in Production account

Comment: I see , see my answer below . And i think when you are using the url  https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx things are working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx` is not a valid DocuSign endpoint.

Try `https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx` instead. Note that if you have not passed the Go Live process, you will not be able to use your integration key in Production. The Go Live process is documented here: https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/go-live-steps

Comment: Thank you Drew. Changing URL to https://www.docusign.net/api/3.0/credential.asmx worked for me.

Comment: @Vin does this answer your question? If so mark it as the answer.